# How to store a Date time with milliseconds into a DateTime Object in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have Dictionary with a key in DateTime object .

```
static Dictionary<DateTime, string> messageList = new Dictionary<DateTime, string>();
```

I wan't to store Date time with milliseconds as key.

```
static Dictionary<DateTime, string> messageList = new Dictionary<DateTime, string>();
```

I want to store the Data time in `01/01/2008 00:30:45.125` format as a key to in Dictionary.

Comment: The `DateTime` type already contains milliseconds.

Comment: So what is the problem you are getting?

Comment: Are you talking about storing DateTime in a particular format?

Comment: Yes. I want to store it in a particular format . i'm making using of the dictionary to send an automated mail.

Comment: You need to construct a new DateTime without the tick-fractions: `DateTime key = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Second, dt.Millisecond);` with `dt` being the original datetime. Or you store a string `dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff");` Note the 24h format to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to store the Data time in 01/01/2008 00:30:45.125 format as a key to in Dictionary.

`DateTime` objects **do not have formats**. They are *binary data* that represent a date and time. You can easily use a `DateTime` object with a value that represents the instant described by `01/01/2008 00:30:45.125` as a dictionary key, but that's not the same thing.

If you need a particular string format, *use a string as the key type*.  But probably you're overthinking this, and you really don't want that particular string format in the Dictionary. After all, you can always take that `DateTime` object and format it for display later on, and that's really the better practice.

The remaining concern is `DateTime` has sub-millisecond precision, meaning you can have more than one `DateTime` value in a single millisecond. If it's possible for your environment to produce two data points within that same millisecond, and you want to make sure they end up in the same place in your dictionary, you'll need to truncate or round the `DateTime` value. I prefer to do this by constructing a new `DateTime` value using the properties from the old, though some calculation using `Ticks` is potentially faster:

```
public DateTime RoundToMillisecond(DateTime original)
{
    return new DateTime(original.Year, original.Month, original.Day, original.Hour, original.Minute, original.Second, original.Millisecond);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget `original.Kind`.  :)

Answer (score 5):

I strongly suspect that you are confusing about between value of a `DateTime` and textual representation of a `DateTime`.

A [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8) instance does *not* have any implicit format. It just have date and time values which based on [`Ticks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netframework-4.8). "Format" concept *only* applies when you get it's *textual* (aka string) representation.

If you *really* want to "store" your data with specific "format" (most of the case you shouldn't), then you need to use `Dictionary<string, string>` instead of `Dictionary<DateTime, string>`.

If you wanna "truncate" the nanoseconds part and keep the milliseconds only, you can use [`DateTime.AddTicks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addticks?view=netframework-4.8) method like;

```
myDateTime = myDateTime.AddTicks( - (myDateTime.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond) / 100);
```

Comment: yes. it works with the string key . But i didn't want to change the definition of the existing dictionary . Hope i don't have any other options than changing the key's datatype .

Comment: There is no need to change the key. Just remove the Ticks from the DateTime!

Comment: @sujandlingaraj Added a solution if you wanna truncate nanoseconds and have only milliseconds as `.125`.

Comment: @TaW Actually based on OP's output (which is `01/01/2008 00:30:45.125`), looks like he wants to truncate nanoseconds part and keep only milliseconds part as `.125`. Edited my answer based on that as well.

Comment: I must have missed your edit. Not sure if that calculation is perferable to the constructor I suggested, though..

Answer (score 2):

The DateTime class already has Millseconds component and your code should work. If you would like to display your date in a specific format, use the ToString() function and specify the appropriate format string.

```
var myDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff");
```

Comment: i want to store it in DateTime variable . I have tried the same Syntax. Is there a way where we can active it without converting it into string , because my Dictionary's key is of DateTime type.

Comment: Are you getting an error with your code? If so, edit your question and add more information. I don't see any problem with the code.

Comment: @Shameel DateTime.Now is a property, not a method.

Comment: _your code should work._ No. As long as he keeps the Ticks it will not work.

Comment: @TaW, the only condition is that each entry in the Dictionary should have a unique key, unique DateTime in this case. And unique is defined by IComparable.

Comment: No! It compiles but the goal is to use a datetime up to the milliseconds as key. Keeping the Ticks could create a large number of entries which all belong to the same millisecond. Btw:  formatting with `hh` instead of `HH` would be prone to false duplicates, that is if the Ticks are removed..

Comment: @TaW I get your point now. But nowhere in my answer, I have mentioned anything about ticks.

Comment: You wrote that his code _should work_. But he doesn't remove the Ticks.. He didn't tell us, but I suspect his problem is that he never could find a key with just the milliseconds..

Comment: @TaW ok, I assumed he will add values to the precision he needs. Thanks for pointing it out.